# StackLayout changes size automagically in kivy framework

Tags: python, kivy

I am using Win7, Eclipse, python 2.7 + kivy framework for developing a openGL app.
I am trying to check some collision points(x, y) of a Widget on a mouse click. I create a layout with a specific size, but when entering the on_touch_down(mouse click) callback the layout size is strangely changed(here is the problem). Let me show you my code:

```
class PlayScreen(Screen):
     layout = None
     def __init__(self):
          self.layout = StackLayout(size=(Types.SCREEN_SIZE_WIDTH, 100))
          #then I create widgets inside the layout:
          self.lblScore = Label(text='SCORE:', size_hint=(.1, .1))
          self.lblScoreValue = Label(text='0', size_hint=(.1, .1))
          .....
          self.layout.add_widget(self.lblScore)
          self.layout.add_widget(self.lblScoreValue)
          #here the debugger shows me self.layout size to be(800, 100)
      #and then I want to test if I click on the self.layout:
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        bCanAddTower = True
        if self.layout.collide_point(touch.x, touch.y) == True:
            print "colision with menu"
        #here self.layout has size=(800, 600)(here is the problem) the entire window size, and of course I get into collision all the time.
```

Does anybody have any idea why the size of the self.layout changes in on_touch_down method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial size is because you instantiate the widget with that size, so all the code you run immediately aftewards sees this value. However, its parent widget is a Screen which is a Layout class (specifically a RelativeLayout) that automatically resizes its children to fill itself unless you set some other options. This automatic resizing only takes place after its `__init__` (but before the next frame), which is why on_touch_down, or any other method, will see the new size.

In this case, you can add `size_hint=(None, None)` to the self.layout instantiation. This simply tells the parent Screen not to manually control its size, so it will remain as you have set it.

In the longer term, you may want to work with some proportional size setting rather than a fixed value, as a totally fixed size won't appear the same way on different screen sizes, pixel densities etc.